# MYSQL/PHP AES_Decrypt function passing value

Tags: php, mysql, encryption

```
 if ($db_found) {
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT *, 
           CAST(AES_DECRYPT(jmeno, 'usa2010') AS CHAR(50)) name,
           CAST(AES_DECRYPT(prijmeni, 'usa2010') AS CHAR(50)) lastname,
           FROM   pacienti WHERE id='13'");

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $together = $row['name'] . " " . $row['lastname'];

        }
      echo  $together;
    }
```

Variable $together is null, but should contain data from table.
screenshot of table output after sql request above [image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to write `echo` in loop

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{
   echo $together = $row['name'] . " " . $row['lastname'];
}
```